# CMake Error: The source directory "/home/jtalbert/build/external/Kokkos" does not exist.（from Kokkos_configure.out）

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

```
~/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-DKOKKOS_DEPENDENCE -DMM_ENABLE_CUDA=ON -DMM_FFT_BACKEND=Heffte ../meumapps/
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.34.1") 
-- Need Kokkos
--     clone
--     configure
-- 
CMake Error at CMake/BuildDependency.cmake:42 (message):
  

              Failed to configure Kokkos
              See "/home/jtalbert/build/external/Kokkos_configure.out"
              
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/BuildKokkos.cmake:23 (build_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've googled about this CMake error, but nothing I got. It's my first time to use CMake in Ubuntu. Looking forward to a solution...

Comment: I have tried to build a directoy according to the 'error' message, and another error occured. CMake Error at CMake/BuildDependency.cmake:42 (message):
  

              Failed to configure Kokkos
              See "/home/jtalbert/build/external/Kokkos_configure.out"
              
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/BuildKokkos.cmake:23 (build_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)

Comment: "_See "/home/jtalbert/build/external/Kokkos_configure.out"_" if this is a log file, please [edit] to show the contents of this file. Also, please provide a links to where meumapps can be cloned from.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.